# OAuth2 - how to authorize without client secret?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to create a frontend application. The app should connect to the Strava API. In the [authentication documentation](http://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/), they say the client secret is required to get the access_token. I don't want to store my client secret in my JavaScript code.

I found a [blog post](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/single-page-apps/) where they explain a way where you don't need to pass the client secret, but it's not working, I get an Authorization Error.

Is it possible to get the access_token without the client secret? If not, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for Implicit Grant flow (Two-Legged) - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2

Strava seems to implement only Authorization Code Grant flow (Three-Legged) which is safer and force you to have a server that holds the secret to complete the handshake - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any server where I can store the client secret? I don't want to pay for this and I looking for the easiest solution, because I want to focus on the frontend part of the application.

Comment: Don't use implicit grant. https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.1.2 and https://medium.com/oauth-2/why-you-should-stop-using-the-oauth-implicit-grant-2436ced1c926

Comment: " which is safer" not necessarily. If I implement auth code grant flow in my on-prem software, I have to store the client_secret in the code which can be decompiled and therefore is vulnerable.